# Refresh Scroll to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, html-table, page-refresh

I have an embed tag, It is embedding another page of my site, I want that embed to scroll down. That embed is actually embedding chat comments from another page, I am updating that page every 3 seconds but I want that embed frame scroll bar to scroll to bottom on every refresh. Any JavaScript or JQuery would be nice, Please help me complete this, I need to submit it some where.

**THE MARKUP**

```
<embed id="embed" src="comments.php" width="200" height="500" border="1"/> <-- This is embed frame
```

Both pages are written in .php file and also comments.php doesn't contain any body/html tag.

**Comments.php**

```
<table id="commentstable">
<?php
    echo"<tr>
        <td class='username'>$username</td>
        <td class='comment'>$comment</td>
            </tr>";
?>
</table>
```

I am using this to refresh the comments frame and page.Only frame is updated but the main page remains static.

```
Header("refresh:3;url='comments.php'");
```

Please, I need the complete code with script tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen to onload event in comments.php and scroll down upon this event. You can use jQuery:

```
$("window").load(scrollDown);
```

**or** use onload property:

```
// your comment.php body tag
<body onload="scrollDown()">
```

Actual scrollDown function can be something like:

```
scrollDown = function() {
   document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
 $('body').scrollTop($(document).height());
});
```